# Multiply array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let arr = ["I", "study", "JavaScript"];
let number = 4;
```

I did tried  arr = arr.map(arr=> arr  *number) but got NaN.
   I want solution like

```
arr= ["I","I", "study","study", "JavaScript","javascript"]
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Can you please give more detail? What does "4" and  ["I","I", "study","study", "JavaScript","javascript"] have to do with each other? Also why is the second javascript lower case?

Comment: so you want number to be 2 or 4 for your expecting result?

Comment: @ghosh : it's amazing that the post was viewed 30+ times and got 0 close votes

Comment: Your question is not clear. Also - the example doesn't make sense. What is the rule here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I know to achieve it, it's using [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
let arr = ["I", "study", "JavaScript"];
let multipliedArr = arr.flatMap(el => [el, el]);
console.log(multipliedArr);
```

Pay attention since it's not supported by Internet Explorer and you may need a polyfill, if you haven't already included it in your bundle.

**Edit**: Generic version:

```js
let arr = ["I", "study", "JavaScript"];
let number = 4;
let multipliedArr = arr.flatMap(el => Array(number).fill(el));
console.log(multipliedArr);
```

Comment: Nice. Mine was far too complex

Answer (score 1):

You can look into `Array.reduce` + `Array.concat`.

Note:

`Array.fill` create instance first and set it to every item. So if you use it with Object, it will set reference instead and any mutation will reflect all

```js
let arr = ["I", "study", "JavaScript"];
let number = 4;

const result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat( new Array(number).fill(item) ), []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple loops:

```js
let arr = ["I", "study", "JavaScript"];
let number = 4;

console.log(multiplyArray(arr, number));

function multiplyArray(arr, multiplier) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < multiplier; j++) {
            newArr.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fill()` and populate a new array:

```js
const arr = ["I", "study", "JavaScript"];

const num = 4;
const newArr = new Array(num * arr.length);
let counter = 0;

for(let item of arr) {
  newArr.fill(item, counter, counter + num);
  counter += num;
}

console.log(newArr);
```

[fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)